# Trying to create new variables by strings from a list

Tags: python, list, csv, variables

I've been scouring the ends of the internet for this, and I am well aware of how discouraged what I am trying to do is. I just can't figure out another way to achieve what I want.
Now, for my actual issue, I have been given a csv containing information of police shootings. The file contains the state of the case, with the city next to it. I want to a variable from each state's name recorded in the csv, and turn them into lists with the contents being the cities in that state. I've read some stuff about globals, but I'm just stumped about where to go from there. The language I'm using is python.

Edit: As requested, here's what the format for the data and my current code:

State|City

Washington|Seattle

California|Los Angeles

Washington|Kirkland

```
PVC = open("PoliceViolence_city.csv", "r", errors="ignore");
KBP = open("KilledByPolice.csv", "r", errors="ignore");

def start(dparse, dparse2):
    cur = [];
    cur2 = [];
    for aa in dparse:
        cur.append(aa);
    for ab in dparse2:
        cur2.append(ab);
    del cur2[0];
    del cur[0];
    for ba in range(len(cur)):
        cur[ba] = cur[ba].split(",");
    sortloc(cur);
    for bb in range(len(cur2)):
        cur2[bb] = cur2[bb].split(",");


def sortloc(dp):
    merge = [];
    state = [];
    city = [];
    s2 = [];
    for a in range(len(dp)):
        if dp[a][0] not in state:
            state.append(dp[a][0]);
        city.append(dp[a][1]);
        s2.append(dp[a][0]);
    for ba in range(len(city)):
        for bb in range(len(state)):
            if s2[ba] == state[bb]:
                print("Matched stuff!");



start(PVC, KBP);
```

Ideally, my output will be something like: Washington = ["Seattle", "Kirkland"].

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: If you can't post any attempts at the code, can you clarify exactly how the information you're given is structured and what you would ideally like the output to look like?

Comment: better use dictionary `data['State Name'] = [...]` - it is more usefull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible by using `eval()`, but you should **REALLY** not do that... a much more structured and safe way to accomplish your task would be to take the state name and make that a key in a dictionary:

```python
txt = '''state1, city1
state2, city2
state2, city3
state3, city4
state3, city4'''

states = {}
for line in txt.split('\n'):
    state, city = line.split(', ')
    if state not in states:
        states[state] = [] #create an empty list to hold all cities in a state
    if city not in states[state]: #don't put the same city in twice
        states[state].append(city) #insert the city into the list


#resulting structure:
#states = {
#    'state1': ['city1'],
#    'state2': ['city2', 'city3'],
#    'state3': ['city4']
#}
```

Comment: the syntax for accessing any given state would be: `states[state]`. this would also give you an easy way to iterate over all the states you have data for by calling `for state in states:` then each "state" is itself a dictionary of all the cities you have information on, and can be accessed in pretty much exactly the same way

Comment: @Davis as for the output structure, I just like to format nested dictionaries that way when I write them as comments, it is just a normal dictionary like everyone else here has suggested.

Comment: @Davis using a dictionary or some other container type is the *only real way to do what you are asking. while it is possible to create global variables with `eval()` it would frankly be much much more work and more complicated than the dictionary method. (not to mention very very unsafe)

Comment: @Davis I simplified my example data to hopefully make it more like what you described in the quesiton..

Comment: Hey, @Aaron. I tried just pasting the code into my IDE to test if it would run, which it didn't. I got a ValueError, apparently there are too many values to unpack. Any ideas as to why? (Deleting previous comments because the sight is warning me for guideline purposes)

Comment: @Davis sorry, I had left a typo in from the first version... see most recent edit

Answer (score 1):

Use `csv.reader` and `collections.defaultdict`:

```
import csv
import collections
with open('states.csv') as f:
    result = collections.defaultdict(list)
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for state,city in reader:
        result[state].append(city)
```

The file:

```
CA,San Francisco
CA,Sacramento
CA,San Francisco
Idaho,Boise
New York,New York City
```

The result:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(result)
{'CA': ['San Francisco', 'Sacramento', 'San Francisco'],
 'Idaho': ['Boise'],
 'New York': ['New York City']}
```

Comment: Hey Tiger, I think you're probably on the best track to help me out, and I'd like to share some screenshots with you. If you're willing, email me at thesilenceisfalling@gmail.com. Thank you!

Comment: SO is not intended for private tutorial services (which is good news for you, because I charge $40/hour for that :)). It is intended as a public QA site where people can look up common programming challenges. If your question was not specific enough, you can edit it (as you have). If you have a different question altogether, it should be a new question. Remember to try your best with what you have before asking, and show your efforts.

Comment: Ooof, okay, sorry about that, still new to this site, and thank you for the help you have provided again. =3

Answer (score 0):

Time to bring this to a close. My friend helped me out by introducing me to dictionaries. The formatting is right for my data, and I have parented all the states to their respective cities. Thank you all for the help! While furas' answer was correct for what I needed, it wasn't very explanatory, so I think the most helpful overall was Aaron, as he went out of his way to try to help me understand. Hope y'all have a good one!